# Could not load type 'ServiceStack.Common.Extensions.ReflectionExtensions'

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

### My Question

I encounter an exception, its message is as following.

```
Could not load type 'ServiceStack.Common.Extensions.ReflectionExtensions' from assembly 'ServiceStack.Common, Version=3.9.38.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

My IDE is `Visual studio 2012`, and the Ormlite.Sqlite.32bit version is `3.9.38`. I got it from `nuget` today. I tried the anyversion for `Ormlite.Sqlite` by `nuget`, including 32 and 64 bit versions.

My models is as followings

```
[Alias("ttconfig")]
public class Config : IHasId<int>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128)]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And, I run into exception when I create tables.

```
OrmLiteConnectionFactory fac = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=ttdb.sqlite;", SqliteDialect.Provider);
using (var db = fac.CreateDbConnection())
{
     //! When call CreateTables(), it throw exception.
     db.CreateTables(false, typeof(Config));
}
```

### StackTrace of the exception.

The StackTrace content is as following

at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConfigExtensions.GetModelDefinition(Type modelType)
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExtensions.CreateTable(IDbCommand dbCmd, Boolean overwrite, Type modelType) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteWriteExtensions.cs:line 65
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExtensions.CreateTables(IDbCommand dbCmd, Boolean overwrite, Type[] tableTypes) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteWriteExtensions.cs:line 42
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0(IDbCommand dbCmd) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.cs:line 17
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadConnectionExtensions.Exec(IDbConnection dbConn, Action`1 filter) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\Expressions\ReadConnectionExtensions.cs:line 55
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.CreateTables(IDbConnection dbConn, Boolean overwrite, Type[] tableTypes) in C:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteWriteConnectionExtensions.cs:line 17
   at TTSampleDataGenerator.Models.TTDbContext.CheckTables() in ....

### Update

When I update to v3.9.39, it still crashes. But I remove and reinstall the v3.9.39 version, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here..

The last commit/merge (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/37e28a0e4e464632870092a065b058ca0caf0d07) is about **"Replaces references to 'ServiceStack.Common.Extensions' namespace (which is now obsolete) with 'ServiceStack.Common' namespace."**

The commit before is about updating version to v3.9.38 (last nuget version = v3.9.39 ?)

So I don't know if the last nuget package has been upload before that commit (you see the date but not the tme ;) ), but I've just compiled Ormlite from lastest sources, and works well..

Comment: The problem seems be fixed at v3.9.39. I had reinstalled the v3.9.39 by `nuget`. And it works well now.

Comment: I confirm. Just cleaned the whole packages, now working well.